# MySql - Alter few tables on the same time

Tags: mysql, alter-table, alter

I have a MySql Db with innoDB tables.

I need to alter a couple of big tables (~50M records), since altering locks the tables I want to make the process as fast as possible.

What is best in term of speed:
1. altering one table at a time
2. alter both tables on the same time (simultaneously)

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really depends on how much memory you have in your server.

When you're doing ALTER TABLE, you really want the table and its largest secondary index (remember innodb clusters the primary key, so PK is stored with the rows) to fit into memory. If it doesn't, it's going to be slow (NB: This discussion assumes the table is not partitioned).

As your table has a *tiny* 50M rows, the chances are it fits in RAM trivially (you have 32G+ on your server, right?) with all its secondary indexes.

If it all fits in the innodb buffer pool, do them in parallel. If it doesn't do them in series.

Try it on your development server which has the same spec as production (obviously configure them with the same size innodb_buffer_pool)

Comment: If the alter is adding a column, would it really help to have indexes in memory? It feels like it needs to write new data on each record and that's going to be on disk.

Comment: Adding a new column always rebuilds the whole table, with all indexes. Rebuilding the table requires reconstructing the indexes even if they don't use the new column.

Answer (score 2):

I did a test.

I created a table with 4 million rows. Very simple table, one column and all values are "dude" for all rows. I then duplicated that table into big_2 containing the exact same data.

My computer is a macbook pro 13.3" from mid 2010 so everything is related to that.

I then did three things.

1. I ran an alter on both tables in serial, it took 34 and 33 seconds to add the column (67s total).
2. I ran alter on both tables in parallell, it took 1.1 min before they returned (basically at the same time) (61s total)
3. I redid the first test and this time it took 35 + 35 seconds (70 in total)

This confirms my suspicion that it won't be any faster in parallel. The most likely reason is that this is almost entirely an operation on disk, and that cannot be paralleled at all.

Comment: Did you have a 20Gb innodb_buffer_pool in that test?

Answer (score 0):

Doing it simultaneously won't give you much gain. It still has to wait until the first is finished to do the second one.

You may prefer to run the queries with a short delay between them so other queries that have been waiting for the lock since the beginning of the first update don't have to wait for the second as well. It your database is serving a website for example, two 15 seconds hangs is better than a single 30 seconds one.

Comment: if i run them simultaneously, i can make it with 2 different mysql processes by connecting with 2 threads, the question is does one process effects the other

Comment: The mechanics of the lock is to synchronize the operations. It prevents them from running in parallel to avoid consistency issues. As long as they both lock the same table, the gain will be minimal. The second query will be parsed and prepared in advance while the first query executes, but the actual time the table is locked will be the same.